# Sort data in Vue.js without plugin

Tags: javascript, sorting, vue.js

How Sort data in Vue.js without plugin. I have json data like this

```
var people = [
  {
    id: 1,
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    email: "jdoe@example.com",
    dob: "12/12/12"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    firstName: "Jane",
    lastName: "Smith",
    email: "jsmith@example.com",
    dob: "11/11/11"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    firstName: "Brian",
    lastName: "Rogers",
    email: "brogers@example.com",
    dob: "10/10/10"
  }
];
```

How to sort them into desc or asc in table and add icon in the table head which is when user click on table head, the icon will be change dynamically.
For example, when data are highest to lowest the icon will be `fa-sort-amount-desc`

My table code look like this

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12" v-if="!laravelData || laravelData.total === 0"><em>No data available.</em></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="table-scrollable">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th> ID</th>
                                    <th> First Name</th>
                                    <th> Last Name</th>
                                    <th> Email </th>
                                    <th> DOB </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr v-for="data in laravelData.data" :key="data.title">
                                    <td> <a :href="data.account_link">@{{ data.id }}</a> </td>
                                    <td> @{{ data.firstName }}</td>
                                    <td> @{{ data.lastName }} </td>
                                    <td class="text-right"> @{{ data.email }} </td>
                                    <td class="text-right"> @{{ data.dob }} </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr v-if="!laravelData || laravelData.total === 0">
                                    <td colspan="13"><em>No data available.</em></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: i think you can use v-bind class='fa-sort-amount-desc':for desc data condition, 'fa-sort-amount-aesc' : for aesc data condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, You need to implement own sorting function to sort the given array of objects, or you can use https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#orderBy. By use lodash I created the following simple demo.

```js
var people = [{
  id: 10,
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  email: "jdoe@example.com",
  dob: "12/12/12"
}, {
  id: 2,
  firstName: "Jane",
  lastName: "Smith",
  email: "jsmith@example.com",
  dob: "11/11/11"
}, {
  id: 3,
  firstName: "Brian",
  lastName: "Rogers",
  email: "brogers@example.com",
  dob: "10/10/10"
}];

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    laravelData: {
      data: people,
    },
    sorting: {
        col: '',
        type: 'asc'
      }
  },
  methods: {
    sort: function(key,type) {
    //if( this.sorting.col){
      this.sorting.col = key;
      this.sorting.type = type 
   // }
     
      this.laravelData.data = _.orderBy(this.laravelData.data, key, this.sorting.type);

      //this.laravelData.data = sortByKey(this.laravelData.data,key)
     
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.16.0/lodash.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" v-if="!laravelData || laravelData.total === 0"><em>No data available.</em></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="table-scrollable">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
              ID 
              <i @click="sort('id','asc')" class="fa fa-sort-asc " aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <i @click="sort('id','desc')" class="fa fa-sort-desc" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </th>
              <th> First Name</th>
              <th> Last Name</th>
              <th> Email </th>
              <th> DOB </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="data in laravelData.data" :key="data.title">
              <td> <a :href="data.account_link">@{{ data.id }}</a> </td>
              <td> @{{ data.firstName }}</td>
              <td> @{{ data.lastName }} </td>
              <td class="text-right"> @{{ data.email }} </td>
              <td class="text-right"> @{{ data.dob }} </td>
            </tr>
            <tr v-if="!laravelData || laravelData.total === 0">
              <td colspan="13"><em>No data available.</em></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can find jsfiddle @ https://jsfiddle.net/sureshamk/zc9wr53g/2/